# How to implement / render two filters separately using react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

How can i implement these two filter with **postRes** in table row ? postRes is json api response. includeKeyword &  searchVolume  is State hook. i don't want to implement filters if states are empty.  i appreciate your help in advance

```
  let includeKeywordResults = !includeKeyword  ? postRes : postRes.filter(data =>
    data.text.toLowerCase().includes(includeKeyword.toLocaleLowerCase())) 
  

 let searchVolumeResults = !searchVolume ? postRes : postRes.filter(data => 
  data.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches > parseInt(searchVolume) )
```

Return

```
        <div className="container table-responsive py-5"> 
      <table className="table table-bordered table-hover" id="table-to-xls">
        <thead className="text-white bg-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Keyword</th>
            <th scope="col">Search Volume</th>
            <th scope="col">Competition</th>
            <th scope="col">CPC</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    {includeKeywordResults !== undefined ? includeKeywordResults.map((data, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{data.text}</td>
            <td>{data.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches}</td>
            <td>{data.keyword_idea_metrics.competition}</td>
            <td>{data.keyword_idea_metrics.low_top_of_page_bid_micros}</td>
          </tr>
  )) : null}
  
  </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a filter function with your various criteria and pass it to the Array.filter prototype. Function will look like something like that (not tested):

```
const filterFunction = (a) => {
   if (!includeKeyword && !searchVolume){
      return true
   } else if (includeKeyword && !searchVolume){
      return a.text.toLowerCase().includes(includeKeyword.toLocaleLowerCase())) 
   } else if (!includeKeyword && searchVolume){
      return  a.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches > parseInt(searchVolume)
   } else {
      a.text.toLowerCase().includes(includeKeyword.toLocaleLowerCase())) && a.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches > parseInt(searchVolume) 
   }
}
```

and pass it before your map:

```
includeKeywordResults.filter(filterFunction).map((data, index) => (
```

Comment: Not all hero wear capes... Thank you very much.

Comment: Please approve and upvote the answer if it works! thanks